# How to find nth element in array?

Tags: c++

This is my function:

```
string *textRows = nullptr;

string getElement(int index) const {
    if (index < sizeof(textRows)) {
        return textRows[index];
    }
    return "";
};
```

should return "" when index is above length of textRows. This code doesn't work in intended way. Do you have any solution or see my mistake?

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You can't de-reference `nullptr`. Is there other code which assigns to that? If so, *what*? `sizeof(textRows)` is the **size of the pointer, not the array**. I'm not sure why you'd need a `getElement` unless the singular purpose here is bounds checking. If so, you're using a signed value and not testing for <0 values. Consider using `size_t` as is the convention in C++.

Comment: Since you're using C++ please avoid using C-style arrays, even pointers to them. Instead use containers like `std::vector` to hold data. These have all sorts of properties, including being able to tell you their size in terms of elements stored.

Comment: Consider using [string::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/)

Comment: @tadman and also sizeof(textRows) will return always 4 bytes, and doing sizeof(*textRows) will produce a segmentation fault... and also the size of a string is not it's length

Comment: Question might be if I correctly assign values into textrows:
`textRows[0] = string1;
textRows[1] = string2;`
is from my code. Is that correct?

Comment: You can't assign *anything* into `textRows` until you make that a valid pointer.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<std::string> textRows` instead and then `textRows.push_back(string1)` and so on.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia No, `sizeof(*textRows)` is perfectly fine if you want to get the size of the `string` type (which is not the length of the string it holds), because it is an unevaluated operand.

Comment: @uneven_mark in the example the pointer is nullptr, so i think sizeof(*nullptr) will produce a segmentation fault

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia `textRows` has a different type than `nullptr`, so your comparison doesn't work. In any case `sizeof`'s argument is an *unevaluated operand*. It is never evaluated at runtime, only the types are determined during compilation. So there is no chance of undefined behavior / segmentation fault due to invalid pointers with it.

Comment: In order to solve my solution I should stay using `string *textRows = nullptr;`. Is there any way how could I solve this using this declaration?

Comment: @bartolomo -- `Is there any way how could I solve this using this declaration?` With that code you came up with?  No.  A pointer knows nothing -- all it knows is what it points to.  It doesn't know anything else -- it doesn't know how many items there are in `textRows`, so how are you going to provide that information?

Comment: You need to do `textRows = new string[SIZE];` once before you read/write to `textRows[i]`.

Comment: @uneven_mark when i've said that textRows is  nullptr type?? never, i've said that it's value is nullptr, so when you try to dereferenciate it, it will produce a segmentation fault, because ITS VALUE is nullptr!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie then assume only declaration part. I guess the rest is not sufficient for that.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia You suggested that `string *textRows = nullptr; auto s = sizeof(*textRows);` is the same as `auto s = sizeof(*nullptr);`, which is wrong because `nullptr` has type `std::nullptr_t`, while `textRows` has type `std::string*`. And again, values of the pointer don't matter in unevaluated contexts, such as `sizeof`. How could they? `sizeof` must be evaluated at compile-time when the pointer's value isn't even known in general.

Comment: So as soon as I do this: `string *textRows = nullptr; textRows = new string[myInt];` I can assign values into textRows like this `textRows[0] = string0; textRows[1] = string1`?

Comment: @bartolomo -- You haven't addressed how to do this:  `if (index < sizeof(textRows))`.  Without `myInt`, there is no way to know the size.  That's the ugliness of doing this -- you have to drag around the number of entries around somehow, unless you encapsulate it, similar to creating a `vector` class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok, I will consider doing it that way (assigning new int value containing number of rows). But anyway, when I try to return even value textRows[0], it does create error only (like I wouldn't assign anything there at all).

Answer (score 1):

You got one severe misconception about `sizeof`. *It doesn't return the size of an array, but the size of a type*. So `sizeof(textRows)` will return the size of a `string *`, which is the same as the size of any pointer, usually 4 or 8 byte.

In standard C++ there is no way to retrieve the size of an array, if just have a pointer. So I suggest you replace the c-style array with c++-style [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::string> textRows;

void fillTextRows()
{
    //Use push_back to fill the vector:
    textRows.push_back("...");
}

std::string getElement(int index) const {
    if (index < textRows.size()) {
        return textRows[index];
    }

    return "";
};
```

Alternative, if you really, really have to use pointers: Remember the size of the array.

```
std::string *textRows = nullptr;
size_t textRowsLen = 0;

void fillTextRows(size_t count)
{
    textRowsLen = count;
    textRows = new std::string[count];

    //put some data in there:
    textRows[0] = "...";
}

std::string getElement(int index) const {
    if (index < textRowsLen) {
        return textRows[index];
    }

    return "";
};
```

That's essentially reinventing the wheel, because `std::vector` was made to abstract exactly this scenario.

Comment: Thank you but in order to solve my solution (by questgiver) I should stay using string *textRows = nullptr;. Is there any way how could I solve this using this declaration?

Comment: The `new[]` alternative is going to be a lot more ugly as it doesn't know its own size.